# Cor function in R producing errors

Tags: r, function, correlation

i'v been trying to write a function that takes a directory of data files and a threshold for complete cases and calculates the correlation between sulfate and nitrate for monitor locations where the number of completely observed cases (on all variables) is greater than the threshold. The function should return a vector of correlations for the monitors that meet the threshold requirement. If no monitors meet the threshold requirement, then the function should return a numeric vector of length 0. There are multiple errors being generated hence i'm not mentioning them here.

The data files for the code are here:
https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdata%2Fspecdata.zip

Code

```
corr<-function(directory, threshold=0){
    files.list=list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE, pattern=".csv")
    comp.sum<-numeric()
    num<-numeric()

    for(i in 1:332){
    data<-read.csv(files.list[i])
    data.cor<-na.omit(data[,2:3])
    comp.sum<-sum(data.cor)
    if
    {
    comp.sum>threshold
    cor.var<-cor(data.cor, use="all.obs")
    }
    else
    {
    num
    }
    }
    cor.var
}
```

Comment: At least there is a condition for ``if`` missing. I think it accidently is within the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the function a bit to get what you would like. This of course assumes that sulfate and nitrate are always in column 2 and 3 and that there are no other csvs in that directory (as if there are numbers in those columns a correlation coefficient would be calculated for something else).

```
corr<-function(directory, threshold=0){
  files.list=list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE, pattern=".csv")
  cors <- rep(0, length(files.list))
  for(i in 1:length(files.list)){
    data<-read.csv(files.list[i], header = TRUE) 
    data.cor<-na.omit(data[,2:3])
    nobs<-nrow(data.cor)
    if(nobs > threshold){
      cors[i]<-cor(data.cor[,1], data.cor[,2])
    }else{
     cors[i] <- 0
    }
  }
  return(cors)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but could you mention the mistake in my code?

Comment: If you put your function next to mine it is pretty apparent where the mistakes are. For example, you are not filling elements in a vector with yours, but rewriting over `cor.var` each time, the line with `cor.var` is inside the `if` statement when it should be after, etc.